# needed mysql query? Select price which value morethan 100000

Tags: mysql

tableName:number_plate

ColumnName:price

My query:

```
SELECT * FROM number_plate WHERE price > 100000
```

it is not returning anything

In column many price's are more than `100000` .

Comment: It's possible that the column price has been declared as a string rather than a numerical datatype - b'coz ur query is good

Comment: Your query seems perfectly fine. Could you please share the table structure and some sample data?

Comment: i have changed to varchar, the result is same

Comment: i got the answere...as same i have changed the data type

Comment: @Shakif no no... varchar is wrong. change it to integer

Comment: price integer ?

Comment: @lazy_coder or double ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comments, I think the problem is with your datatype.

Please change the datatype of the price column to Double OR you can use [cast](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast) to change the datatype in the query.